# Enable Enhanced Domains

Tags: digital-experience, release-update

We are planning to enable "Use enhanced domains" for our org. According to the Release Update "Enable Enhanced Domains" we found that the hard-coded host of salesforce and digital experience site needs to be fixed.

We are using the custom domain in the Salesforce digital experience site so is this URL also getting changed on production after enabling "Enable Enhanced Domains"? Do we still need to replace the hard-coded URL throughout the org metadata?

We are assuming that the connected app like (Pardot, Marketing Cloud, Dell Boomi) will work fine afterward, is there anything we need to check and update or test kindly mention.

Comment: Covered in FAQ: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_enhanced_considerations.htm&type=5

Comment: @identigral It means that if we are using a custom domain for the experience cloud site then there will be no impact on production, I understand it right?

Comment: You can also check this discussion group on [Enhanced Domain](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F94S000000kF9qSAE?lang=en&tab=discussion&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC)